# DHCP handling between home router and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

So I have added a server at a school. The computer has Windows Server 2012 R2.

What is the best solution to Add the Windows Server with DHCP but at the same time allow the router to give out IP Addresses to individuals that are not going to join the local / internal domain?

For instance there will be 10 employees on TESTLAB.internal Domain (joined)

Also there are students and other staff that are not going to be on the domain. These can use the wifi to get internet but will not be part of the local domain.

Is there a way to split dhcp handling between Windows Server and the router?

Is it possible to leave DHCP on both the router and Windows Server but split ranges of assigned IP Addresses to avoid issues. Or is this a bad setup?

Any information on this would help.

Thanks

Comment: What would be different between the DHCP settings you assigned the domain and non-domain clients?

Comment: I think the difference would be the ranges of IP Addresses. For instance domain clients: 192.168.0.100 - 200 vs non domain clients 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.99. Im wondering if perhaps this is a bad setup.

Comment: The reason I ask is because, unless you have some specific requirement, you can serve domain and non-domain clients with the same DHCP server without trouble. But I don't want to post that as an answer if you have some retirement to the contrary.

Comment: Thanks Twisty Impersonator. The reason I want to do it this way is because I want to be sure that non domain users will still be able to use the internet even if the Server goes down or is turned off for some reason.

Comment: Is that something that is likely to happen, or if it did would be down for several days? Also, are the domain and non-domain clients on the same LAN? Could the be put on separate networks/VLANs?

Comment: Yeah, and it does happen. Sometimes the internet has gone down. For maybe a day. The clients are on the same LAN but I've set them up on different 'ranges' of dhcp. I haven't learned about VLANs yet. Im still teaching myself and haven't gotten to that yet.